# Linux kernel windows-like event implementation

Tags: c, events, linux-kernel, synchronization

We need to implement Windows-like kernel event for Linux. These functions are intended to behave as corresponding *KeInitializeEvent*, *KeSetEvent*, *KeResetEvent*, *KePulseEvent*, and *KeWaitForSingleObject* from Windows kernel. *Synchronization* event is called *auto reset* here, and *Notification* event is called *manual reset*. Here is the code:

Event.h

```
#define WAIT_FOREVER     -1

#define event_init(event, manual_reset, initial_state) __event_init(event, manual_reset, initial_state)
#define event_set(event) __event_set(event)
#define event_reset(event) __event_reset(event)
#define event_pulse(event) __event_pulse(event)
#define event_wait(event, ms_timeout) __event_wait(event, (ms_timeout == WAIT_FOREVER) ? (WAIT_FOREVER) : ((ms_timeout * HZ) / 1000))

typedef struct _wait_t
{
    atomic_t b;
    wait_queue_head_t q;
    struct list_head list;
} wait_t;

typedef struct _event_t
{
    struct list_head Wait;
    bool AutoReset;
    bool State;
} event_t;

void __event_init_lib(void);
void __event_init(event_t *event, bool manual_reset, bool initial_state);
bool __event_set(event_t *event);
bool __event_reset(event_t *event);
bool __event_pulse(event_t *event);
status_t __event_wait(event_t *event, time_t timeout);
```

Event.c

```
wait_t g_stor[100];
spinlock_t g_lock;

void __event_init_lib(void)
{
    wait_t *ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(g_stor); ++i)
    {
        ptr = &g_stor[i];
        atomic_set(&ptr->b, 2);
        init_waitqueue_head(&ptr->q);
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&ptr->list);
    }

    spin_lock_init(&g_lock);
}

void __event_init(event_t *event, bool manual_reset, bool initial_state)
{
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&event->Wait);

    event->State = initial_state;
    event->AutoReset = !manual_reset;
}

status_t __event_wait(event_t *event, time_t timeout)
{
    bool b;
    wait_t *ptr;
    status_t status;

    spin_lock(&g_lock);
    if (event->State)
    {
        if (event->AutoReset) event->State = false;
        spin_unlock(&g_lock);
        return s_success;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(g_stor); ++i)
    {
        ptr = &g_stor[i];
        if (atomic_cmpxchg(&ptr->b, 2, 0) == 2) break;
    }
    list_add_tail(&ptr->list, &event->Wait);            // note: we need to insert in the end of the list
    spin_unlock(&g_lock);

    if (timeout == WAIT_FOREVER) wait_event(ptr->q, b = (atomic_cmpxchg(&ptr->b, 1, 2) == 1));
    else wait_event_timeout(ptr->q, b = (atomic_cmpxchg(&ptr->b, 1, 2) == 1), timeout);

    if (b) status = s_success;
    else status = s_timeout;

    return status;
}

bool __event_set(event_t *event)
{
    bool PrevState;
    struct list_head *entry;
    wait_t *Wait;

    //if (!event->AutoReset && event->State) return true;
    spin_lock(&g_lock);
    PrevState = event->State;
    event->State = true;
    if (!PrevState && !list_empty(&event->Wait))             // check if we became signaled right now
                                                             // and we have waiters
    {
        if (event->AutoReset)
        {
            entry = event->Wait.next;
            Wait = container_of(entry, wait_t, list);
            atomic_set(&Wait->b, 1);
            wake_up(&(Wait->q));
            event->State = false;
            list_del(entry);
        }
        else
        {
            entry = event->Wait.next;
            while (entry != &event->Wait)
            {
                Wait = container_of(entry, wait_t, list);
                atomic_set(&Wait->b, 1);
                wake_up(&(Wait->q));
                entry = entry->next;
                list_del(entry->prev);
            }
        }
    }
    spin_unlock(&g_lock);
    return PrevState;
}

bool __event_reset(event_t *event)
{
    bool PrevState;

    spin_lock(&g_lock);
    PrevState = event->State;
    event->State = false;
    spin_unlock(&g_lock);
    return PrevState;
}

bool __event_pulse(event_t *event)
{
    bool PrevState;
    struct list_head *entry;
    wait_t *Wait;

    spin_lock(&g_lock);
    PrevState = event->State;
    if (!PrevState && !list_empty(&event->Wait))           // check if we became signaled right now
                                                           // and we have waiters
    {
        if (event->AutoReset)
        {
            entry = event->Wait.next;
            Wait = container_of(entry, wait_t, list);
            atomic_set(&Wait->b, 1);
            wake_up(&(Wait->q));
            list_del(entry);
        }
        else
        {
            entry = event->Wait.next;
            while (entry != &event->Wait)
            {
                Wait = container_of(entry, wait_t, list);
                atomic_set(&Wait->b, 1);
                wake_up(&(Wait->q));
                entry = entry->next;
                list_del(entry->prev);
            }
        }
    }
    event->State = false;
    spin_unlock(&g_lock);
    return PrevState;
}
```

I think each waiting thread needs its own condition variable, because if we have one condition variable and set it to *true*, new waiter may arrive and pass through *wait_event* unintentionally without even falling to sleep. So we need to maintain list of condition variables, hence to wake up correct thread we also need multiple wait queues. Also **ReactOS** source suggest that event maintains the list of waiters.

Since we can't use *thread local storage* variables in kernel mode (at least in no easy way) I decided to implement array of wait blocks. When we need to insert waiter in the list we loop this array in search for free wait block. This leads me to believe that we need to use single global lock as **ReactOS** does (dispatcher lock), not separate lock for each event object.

We need event object for our video camera driver ported from Windows. Everything seems to work fine, however frames per second sometimes drops from 14 fps to 10 (and image flickers). It led me to believe that there is something wrong with the implementation of event.

If you have some suggestions, please share. Thank you.

Comment: If you do not want to wait for someone, who is expert in **both** Windows and Linux kernel, then it is better to describe what event-related function are intended to do. In the code with a few comments it is difficult to understand what you are doing and what do you want. From the view of the Linux kernel programming, `wait_event`-family functions should **not** be called with a spinlock held. (In your code you hold spinlock `ptr->Lock` and call `wait_event` or `wait_event_timeout`). Why do you ever need to implement a queue over the waitqueue?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think each waiting thread needs its own condition variable, because if we have one condition variable and set it to true, new waiter may arrive and pass through wait_event unintentionally without even falling to sleep. So we need to maintain list of condition variables, hence to wake up correct thread we also need multiple wait queues.

Comment: These functions are intended to behave as corresponding KeInitializeEvent, KeSetEvent, KeResetEvent, KePulseEvent, and KeWaitForSingleObject from Windows kernel. Synchronization event is called "auto reset" here, and Notification event is called "manual reset".

Comment: Nice, this is very valuable info. Add content from the both comments into the question post.